# Is there any way to "git reset --hard" in the VSCode app?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to run `git reset` commands using the VSCode graphic interface? It seems like every other git operation is available. If not, then how can a GUI user resolve rewritten history on the remote?

If I pull a branch, and then someone else in the world runs `git commit amend && git push --force` to my branch so that the hash of the HEAD has changed, does VSCode's git interface offer any way of resolving that? From a terminal I would normally just `git fetch && git reset --hard origin/my-branch`, but I work with people not comfortable on the command line. Is there any way to express to VSCode "abandon what I have without reservation and set my code to the latest remote"

[image of vscode command palette search for "Git: reset"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJdJ0.png)

Comment: the `git reset` variants are used very rarely, and are dangerous if you do not know what you are doing. just use them on the command line

Comment: @rioV8 i don't agree that git reset are used rarely or that they are dangerous. i reset hard at least once a week. it just depends on the workflow and branch organization that your team is using. any destructive operation can also be reversed using the reflog, so the main reason to avoid resets is overstated. it's true that altering the history can be fraught for inexperienced users, but usually only when they are pushing.

in my context, a qa person is pulling code but never pushing. there is no danger in their using resets and rewrite commands when they never push.

Comment: if you as a qa don't commit and push you can just use a detached HEAD, checkout a particular commit hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install the [GitLens extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens), you can use that to perform a `git reset`:

[image]

After you select this command, it will display a list of commits to reset to, and then after choosing a commit, it will ask you how you want to reset (i.e. `hard`, `soft`, etc).

Gitlens also adds quite a lot more to the "git experience" for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Doesn't seem to let you specify a branch or a tag which is quite a weakness.